# Runtime Error 6 - Overflow in Excel VBA When Using Scripting.FileSystemObject

Tags: excel, vba, overflow, filesystemobject

Hopefully someone can shed some light on a problem that's just cropped up with some code that's been working faultlessly for years.

I have a VBA form and code in a spreadsheet that opens another workbook, writes some data to that workbook then closes it and continues.  The code has been working for all users for years now without me touching it.  But now I'm getting an Overflow error.

Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
Private Sub Check_Installation_Spreadsheet()

    Dim Installation_Spreadsheet_Lock As String
    Dim Installation_Spreadsheet As String
    Dim obj_installWB As Object
    Dim obj_installWS As Object
    Dim objfso As Object
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim MonthYear As String
    Dim FinancialYear As String
    Dim install_Day As String
    Dim Mon_Wed As String
    Dim Wed_Fri As String
    Dim loopcounter As Integer
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim tmpString As String
    Dim tmpDDStart As String
    Dim tmpInstallDate As Date
    Dim tmp6WeekTrialDate As Date
    
    FinancialYear = Range("FinancialYear")
    
    Installation_Spreadsheet_Lock = "S:\2-SBS\SBS-CustomerAccounts\~$Master installation sheet for finance 2024.xlsx"
    Installation_Spreadsheet = "S:\2-SBS\SBS-CustomerAccounts\Master installation sheet for finance 2024.xlsx"

    Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objfso.FileExists(Installation_Spreadsheet) Then
        If objfso.FileExists(Installation_Spreadsheet_Lock) Then
            MsgBox ("The file is locked by " & GetFileOwner(Installation_Spreadsheet_Lock))
            verify_Continue = "No"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox ("The file is available")
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' *** The next line is the line where the process is failing ***

            Set obj_installWB = Workbooks.Open(Installation_Spreadsheet)

            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            verify_Continue = "Yes"
        End If
    Else ' The master installation spreadsheet doesn't exist
        MsgBox ("The master installation spreadsheet " & Installation_Spreadsheet & " does not exist")
        verify_Continue = "No"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

As stated, this code has worked for years without any issue.

The workbook that the code opens had around 8,500 rows in the worksheet being accessed so I tried deleting around half of those but I still got the overflow error.

Comment: How big is the Excel file in `Installation_Spreadsheet`? Also, why do you declare `obj_installWB ` as `Object` instead of as `Workbook`?

Comment: Does the workbook you open trigger any code (eg Workbook_Open)? The `Open`-command itself cannot create an overflow error, but maybe the code in the opened workbook does.

Comment: What version(s) of Excel are you using ?

Comment: What does `FileSystemObject` have to do with the error? `Workbooks.Open` is not a member.  What happens if you just run a macro like:`Dim obj_installWB As Object: Set obj_installWB = Workbooks.Open("S:\2-SBS\SBS-CustomerAccounts\Master installation sheet for finance 2024.xlsx")` (*assuming the workbook exists*). Do you still get the Overflow error?  If not, are you certain the error is coming from that statement?

Comment: Which line is your error thrown at?

Comment: Great Question! It would be helpful, if you could provide some more details about the version of Excel in which it was created, the current version, where it has crashed and may the dependent code.

Comment: You should check the `Dim loopcounter As Integer` as integer in vba holds only values from -32k to +32k and excel spreadsheet contains more than 1M rows. In case you try to assign integer value which is more than defined in type - you'll get an Overflow exception

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for the comments.  Couldn't see a way in which I could respond to each one so hopefully this covers everyone.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns the size of the Installation_Spreadsheet file is 1.8mb  It's a fully forms driven interface so the end user doesn't see the underlying spreadsheet at all, they just interact with the forms.
As far as why I'm using Object instead of Workbook, I can't actually remember. I was looking for a solution many years ago and came across the object method and it worked and has sat there ever since.

Comment: @FunThomas No, the workbook being opened has no code in it. Just a bog standard workbook.

Comment: @CDP1802 The Excel version is showing as Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2312 Build 16.0.17126.20190) 64 bit.  The Workbook that is running the code is being saved as Excel 97-2003 Workbook.  This is because with some Office upgrades in the past everything would break and the solution offered was to keep it as Excel 97-2003

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Apologies, I was looking for a suitable title and I've homed in on the wrong thing.
I will have to try your suggestion but not in a position to do that at the moment.

Comment: @LajosArpad the error is being thrown by the line indicated in the code segment:
' *** The next line is the line where the process is failing ***

            Set obj_installWB = Workbooks.Open(Installation_Spreadsheet)

Comment: @CharlesdeM. Excel version has been detailed in one of the previous comments.  Where it's crashed is as shown in the code segment.  There's no dependent code I can think of other than what's shown?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Thanks for the warning, but I don't think this will be a problem. As mentioned in the original post, the workbook being opened is currently at 8,500 rows and that covers dates back to 2019.  The whole solution is being replaced by a more robust system later this year so I just need it to limp through until then.

Comment: @DavidJones Thanks. Let me know what happens when you try my suggested code all by itself in a new workbook.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've had a chance to try running that macro and yes, it opened the target spreadsheet with no errors.

Comment: Hi everyone. I think I've solved it!! I revisited some of your comments and reran the debugging and discovered that I was one line out in the line that was actually throwing the error. It wasn't the Workbook Open line but the Row Count. 

``` Set obj_installWS = obj_installWB.Worksheets("2019 on") rowCount = obj_installWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count For loopcounter = 1 To rowCount ``` 

Opened the Finance spreadsheet and found the old problem that someone had managed to put some data somewhere and basically the last row of the spreadsheet was was 1048576

Comment: And apologies for the lack of code formatting in previous comment.  I'm sure I used the correct markup but just won't format it as code.  Sorry!!

Anyway, thank you so much to everyone that offered help.

Comment: For comments, you'd typically use "`" your code and then the same after your code. Just one, not three :)